# Undefined start while creating project using expo init Project_name

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

**I need Help**
After i create a project using expo init ,it always shows this message : undefined start

Comment: you need to research a little bit yourself and be more specific with details and code snippets

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I cannot comment on this, thus I can only reply as an answer.

I also got the same message asking me to run `undefined start`. It should mean `npm start`.

Are you using `nvm`? I am on Mac Catalina, with `nvm` and `node` v12.14.1. I am wondering if this is related to using `nvm`.

Answer (score 0):

I installed yarn to fix this problem.